# Regular Expression to match numeric OR specific word

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regular expression that handles 0-9 * or basically \d* but also include the or (|) with an expression to handle a specific word. So the idea im shooting for should be this

\d*|[Word]

The reason i need this to happen is i have a filter textbox with my validator applied to it to prevent bogus data being entered, but the trick is i have the default text of the textbox set to what is to be entered into the box, such as "Enter Account." I need the regular expression to handle \d* for the account number validation and the | part of the expression to allow the default text of the textbox to pass validation. I do checking on the back end so this default text wont break the app. I have 3 filter boxes where i'll be using this expression..if possible.

Comment: What if you simply remove the two brackets that are surrounding the `Word`?

Comment: haha the question was what expression do i need to get both sides of the expression to pass. The above expression and the current suggestions have failed :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have it, but lose the `[]`, which indicate character classes:

```
^\d*|word$
```

Also, you should anchor your validation expressions with `^` and `$`.

Comment: I tried the above suggestions and numeric piece passes but the word does not. I tried a validation testing site also and it fails there to.

Comment: ValidationExpression="^\d*|Enter Account No$" this is what im trying to get passed.

Comment: What language are you using? Odd that you have unescaped backslashes in double quotes. In any case the regex is fine so perhaps the word isn't exactly "Enter Account No" as you suspect? Try printing the user input just before validation, to check.

Comment: Im using vb.net and aspx...i'll try the printing, maybe its adding on a char or something?

Comment: Is another option to do this...create validation groups, one for the numeric side and one for the word? then have 2 validations per textbox and depending on which fails, that rev message gets displayed? I'm having no luck on the expression passing. If i do this \d* | Word...then the word gets picked up but the numeric side doesnt. Ideas?

Comment: My work around is actually working, it validates like it should but seems like there would be an expression that works. Not sure why the above expressions do not work because they 100% should,unless whats being validated isnt equal to the expression. The strange part is that even on the test site where i type out the test phrase..it still failed so even the idea of extra/missing data is iffy...i dunno but the validation groups is a work around for now.

Comment: @user1732364 - Adding a space worked? Try this: `\d*| Word`. If that works, that means your word actually is preceded by a space, in which case I'd generalize the whole thing to `^\s*(\d*|Word)\s*$`.

Comment: I went with the dual expressions, its working out so far, thx for the help guys! I'll mark the above expression as an answer cause it does work to a degree.